# Err :java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8000): connect failed:

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am trying to connect to Android emulator via Android Studio IDE.  I am on the Mac running PHP server using command php -S localhost:8000(because this worked in IoS using XCODE IDE). I have an Async task I want to run to wrie data to SQL server via addtoDB method.  Several posts suggested using 10.0.2.2. And i used it.  However I still get the same error.  The following is my code.  It is very simple but does not work.  Also I cannot ping 10.0.2.2.I tried localhost and that gave same error.  At one point it did work by saying it is connected to the php server but it always gave (unexpected end of file) on the PHP window. The PHP code is show after the Java code.

I would like to  say that on IoS this works everytime and I have successfully ported the app ot iphone and using it.  What am I doing wrong here.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Ramesh

```
class doHTTPPost extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

/*
private String Url;
private Integer tos;

public  doHTTTPPost(String url, Integer typeOfService) {
    Url = url;
    tos = typeOfService;
}
*/
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //now call your ipify method which is doing the networking or calling a method that might be doing the networkign

    //getContents("http://localhost:8080");
    String result ="";

    result = addToDb();

    return result;
}

private String addToDb() {



    String urlParameters  = "Fname=Ram&Lname=Ramesh&Msisdn=6785459898";
    byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
    int    postDataLength = postData.length;
    //String request        = "http://example.com/index.php";
    //let myUrl = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/serviceadd-all-good.php/")
    String request = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/serviceaddAndroid.php/";

    URL url=null;

    try {
         url = new URL(request);
        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput( true );
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
        conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
        conn.setUseCaches( false );
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write( postData );
        } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("Err :"+e);

        Log.i("Add","Error");
        return("Error");
    }

    Log.i("Add","Done");

    return("Done");
}
```

The PHP code is

```
<?php
$dir = 'sqlite:/Users/lakshmi/Documents/ServiceTesting.sqlite';
$dbh  = new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database");
// Read request parameters
$fname = $_REQUEST["Fname"];
$lname = $_REQUEST["Lname"];
$msisdn = $_REQUEST["Msisdn"];

//$dbh->exec(  "INSERT INTO Service_Testing (ID, Status, Tech) VALUES ('$id','$status','$tech')");

$dbh->exec( "INSERT INTO TestWithAndroid (Fname, Lname, Msisdn ) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$msisdn')");

//$dbh->exec("INSERT INTO Result (Serial, Testid, Result) VALUES ('$serial','$testid','$result')");
//echo "Row inserted \n";
//$dbh->exec('INSERT INTO Result (Serial, Testid, Result) VALUES (5,"st3","Fail")');
//echo "Row inserted \n";

// Send data back
//echo json_encode($returnValue);

?>
```

Comment: THis isn't a programming error, its a network error.  If you can't even ping it, then the code is doing the right thing.

Comment: So what should I do?  Is 10.0.2.2 incorrect?  I can access other URLs just fine, but not able to access the SQL on my laptop.